# Why is Spyder 2.2.5 not using syntax color scheme on non-py scripts?

Tags: python-2.7, spyder, color-scheme

I am using Spyder 2.2.5 with Python 2.7 (I cannot use any other version of either of these - so updating not an option). I have set the Syntax color scheme in `Tools > Preferences > Editor > Syntax color scheme` to `Spyder/Dark`. This successfully changes the color scheme on py scripts to the intended dark color scheme. However, other file types don't change. They remain the default black on white background (in particular I'm trying work with my bashrc file).

I've never seen this problem before, but I've only worked on newer versions of both Spyder and Python 3.x.

Any ideas why this is happening? Or can anyone point to a related solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) I think that version of Spyder applied our syntax highlighting themes to Python files only, sorry.